# Searching for string in a list of lists

Tags: python, search

I've been trying to add a function to my code which allows the user to search for certain keywords within a list of lists. It only works when the input is identical to the element but I want every element that contains the input to show.

```
infil = open("books.txt" , "r")
books_string = infil.read()
infil.close()
books_li = books_string.splitlines()
books_li.sort()

li_to_present= []
for element in books_li:
    parts = element.split(",")
    li_to_present.append(parts)

user_in = input("Search: ")
matches = [x for x in li_to_present if user_in in x]
```

Example:
Part of the list `li_to_present` is:

```
['Birgitta Trotzig', ' Dykungens dotter'], ['Bo Giertz', ' Stengrunden']
```

If the users input is `"Birgitta"` it won't append to the new list matches

Does anyone have a nice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function on a generator which yields whether the user input is in each string the sub-lists.

```
user_in = input("Search: ")
matches = [l for l in li_to_present if any(user_in in s for s in l)]
```

E.g.

```
>>> li_to_present = [['Birgitta Trotzig', ' Dykungens dotter'],
                     ['Bo Giertz', ' Stengrunden']]
>>> user_in = input("Search: ")
Search: Birgitta
>>> matches = [l for l in li_to_present if any(user_in in s for s in l)]
>>> matches
[['Birgitta Trotzig', ' Dykungens dotter']]
```

Comment: Thank you, now it actually appends the element. But do you know how I can append the whole list which contains the element "Birgitta", i.e. ['Birgitta Trotzig', ' Dykungens dotter'] to the matches list?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

infil = open("books.txt" , "r")
books_string = infil.read()
infil.close()
books_li = books_string.splitlines()
books_li.sort()


li_to_present = []
for element in books_li:
    parts = element.split(",")
    li_to_present.append(parts)

user_in = input("Search: ")
matches = [x for x in li_to_present if re.search(user_in, x)]
```